# Play! Scala Template Engine and Sessions

Tags: scala, mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.0, salat

I would like a user in my web application to make a post. The post will contain his username to indicate he posted it. How would I do this?

**UPDATE!**

This my working code

Please see my code below:

```
        def createlisting = isAuthenticated { username => implicit request =>
          Ok(html.createlisting(listingsForm))
        }

        def postlisting = withUser {user => implicit request => {
          listingsForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
            formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.createlisting(formWithErrors)),
            listing => {
              val username = val username = User.getUserName(user)
              Listings.create(listing.categorytype, listing.title, listing.description, username)
              Redirect(routes.Application.active).flashing("success" -> "Listing %s has been posted".format(listing.title))
              }
            )
            }
          }

        val listingsForm = Form(
          mapping(
            "_id" ->  ignored(new ObjectId()),
            "categorytype" -> mapping(
              "category" -> nonEmptyText,
              "subcategory" -> nonEmptyText)(Type.apply)(Type.unapply),
            "title" -> nonEmptyText,
            "description" -> nonEmptyText,
            "username" -> igrnored(String)
          )(Listings.apply)(Listings.unapply)
        )
```

scala.html

```
                @(createForm: Form[Listings])

                @import helper._

                @implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(twitterBootstrapInput.f) } 

                    <h1>Add a Listing</h1>

                    @form(routes.Application.postlisting()) {

                        <fieldset>
                            @inputText(createForm("categorytype.category"), '_label -> "Main Category")
                            @inputText(createForm("categorytype.subcategory"), '_label -> "Sub Category")
                            @inputText(createForm("title"), '_label -> "Title")
                            @inputText(createForm("description"), '_label -> "Description")

                        </fieldset>

                        <div class="actions">
                            <input type="submit" value="Post Add" class="btn primary" href="/"> or 
                            <a href="/" class="btn primary">Cancel</a> 
                        </div>

                    }
```

What can I do to have the username automatically passed to the postlistings function and save in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the username is in the session (as would appear from the use of `withUser` in the other function), you have nothing to do, it will be passed automatically with each request.

What you do need to do is recover it, though. It would appear that you can just wrap your `Action` in another call to `withUser` and that would just work.

Comment: What would be the syntax html file? Currently what I have is incorrect.

Comment: You don't need anything related to the session in the view, only in the controllers. You are already passing the user name as an argument, which is all you need if you want to e.g. display it to them.

Comment: Ok, I will test again when I have the chance, much respect.